# Changing focus from FM radio to Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-mediasession

I'm developing an app which purpose is to play music through Bluetooth and handles media buttons. I've successfully achieved using code as such:

```
private void startSession() {
    if(mAudioManager == null) {
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }
    mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    ComponentName eventReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), BluetoothMediaButtonReceiver.class.getName());
    mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(eventReceiver);
    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(eventReceiver);
    PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if(mMediaSessionCompat != null) {
            mMediaSessionCompat.release();
        }
        mMediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayerServiceMediaSession", eventReceiver, mediaPendingIntent);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setMediaButtonReceiver(mediaPendingIntent);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);
    } else {
        if(mMediaSession != null) {
            mMediaSession.release();
        }
        mMediaSession = new MediaSession(this, "PlayerServiceMediaSession");
        mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mMediaSession.setActive(true);
        mMediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(mediaPendingIntent);
    }
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

To play music i'm using a service, to handle buttons presses i'm using receiver:

```
public class BluetoothMediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public final static String ACTION_BUTTON_PREVIOUS = "media.button.clicked";
public final static String ACTION_BUTTON_NEXT = "media.button.nex";
public final static String ACTION_BUTTON_PLAY = "media.button.play";
public final static String ACTION_BUTTON_PAUSE = "media.button.pause";
public final static String ACTION_BUTTON_PLAY_PAUSE = "media.button.play_pause";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
                // code for fast forward
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                //Toast.makeText(context, "next button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_BUTTON_NEXT));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_BUTTON_PLAY_PAUSE));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_BUTTON_PLAY));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_BUTTON_PAUSE));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_BUTTON_PREVIOUS));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:
                // code for rewind
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                // code for stop
                break;
        }
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

}

I'm changing Metadata in `onMediaPlayerStart` and such standard stuff, and everyting is working great, **BUT** this is the issue:

After connecting to car audio system and playing music - car audio mode is stays at FM radio for example, if it was there, and i have to manually change it to Bluetooth in the car

**What i want to achieve:** I want to programatically change car audio mode from FM radio to bluetooth when my app is starting to play a track

*I've googled it and searched here on stack, but have nothing on this case, i'm not even sure what class suppose to do such things. I understand this question might be seen as a bad one and without focus, but it's because my knowledge of working with Bluetooth on Android is grim too, it's very hard to find some exanples on this matter*

Comment: I don't think you have the access level to change the playback mode of your car from your phone.

Comment: @F43nd1r, thxs for response, but there are some apps that actually changing it, the mst popular example is this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audible.application, it's actually forcing car to change it, so it's possible then

Comment: In this case I suspect this is an AVRCP/A2DP command. I wasn't able to find a specification though

Comment: @F43nd1r, but if it is, that's a good start :) i thought it will be easier though, but the lack of material proposing otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can not change audio mode of car infotainment system until u don't known about how car infotainment system handle media mode.

By default android play songs in Music-Stream but Bluetooth , FM radio, RNVC etc. are play in different stream(can be customized during framework design).

So if you want to achieve this then you have to ask to them which stream they using for FM, Bluetooth etc.

Comment: Hi, thx for response, something to grab on! But wait, so if i know which stream is used, what should i do next? How can i change it? And also, are you talking about setVolumeControlStream(..) method of an Activity class?

Comment: No changing audio mode is not part of activity. As u know that for play any song u hve to use AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC . so i m talking abt same for FM, bluetooth etc.

Comment: Firstly, i initally thought that audiofocus is handling this, but i was wrong, secondly, So you're telling me that STREAM_MUSIC is actually settings FM rardio? It seems to me that nothing just changing in car

Comment: And also i've been looking on all of the stream types and i cant find anything that has any relation to bluetooth